# SSL installation in Plesk 9.5

Tags: ssl, plesk

I am using plesk 9.5. When i try to set up a ssl certificate from plesk - it ask for Private key , Certificate and CA certificate. Can anyone please let me know which private key should be used over here. Also would like to know about the detail procedure to setup SSL through plesk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these instructions: http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/questions/457/Installing+a+SSL+Certificate+in+Plesk+9

Comment: link not working